# What is this piece? 2 axle and 1 pin?

Tags: part-identification, technic

[image]

I've been looking around for this piece, google images etc, cannot find it.  Any ideas on a part number?

Comment: One of its common names is 'beam thin 1x3'. It is also called a 'liftarm thin 1x3'. and it is in 'blue' ('bright blue' in lego digital designer)

Comment: excellent thanks. I'm new to trying to identify the pieces, it's quite hard!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it:

[6632](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=1555#T=C)

It's the Technic, Liftarm 1x3 Thin piece.